# Is there a possibility to increase font size of the spark label truncation tip in Flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, label, flash-builder, flex-spark

I use Spark Label (Flex 4.6 SDK) in my project to show some text on a form and in case when the text does not fit in one line a truncation tip is shown (using maxDisplayedLines="1" and showTruncationTip="true" properties). But the font size in the tip is very small and I want to increase it but actually I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is doable but not so easy to see how at first.

showTruncationTip tells the label to create a toolTip if isTruncated is true when you mouse over it. So with this knowledge, we can listen for the events that get fired regarding the tooltip being created and do some replacing or stylizing of the toolTip.

```
private var myTip:IToolTip;

// somewhere in your code
label.addEventListener(ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_SHOWN, createCustomTip);

private function createCustomTip(event:ToolTipEvent):void {
    myTip = event.toolTip;
    // do stuff to the existing toolTip or replace it with a custom one
}
```

There is full docs on how to create and replace custom tool tips here [Creating Custom Tool Tips](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler answer. See this link

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/22/changing-the-background-color-of-an-error-tip-in-flex/

and observe how they use `<mx:Style>` tags to modify the default CSS properties for `.errorTip`.